# What is maximum size of the Queue in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, asic

I am writing code to check the pulse width of the clock. I am storing the width of the pulse inside the queue.  Since the simulation is going to run for 2 seconds, the size of the queue is going to enormous. I wanted to know what is the maximum size of the queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look in the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.10 *Queues*, I do not see a maximum size for a queue explicitly specified.  In that case, I would assume that you can not rely on it to be any specific value.  It might depend on your simulation software and on your OS.

I do see this in the Std:

```
7.10.2.1 Size()
The prototype for the size() method is as follows:
    function int size();
```

`int` is specified as signed 32-bit.  Perhaps we can assume a maximum of about 2 billion.

In order to avoid having a huge queue, you should check the pulsewidth on every cycle of the clock.  There should be no need to wait until the end of the simulation.